How to set location in Langchain for Google ChatVertexAI model
Is there anyone know how to set location in Langchain for Google ChatVertexAI model? Langchain document does not mention this.
I have tried with following way but did not work, still use default 'us-central1' location in my tests.
import { ChatVertexAI } from "@langchain/google-vertexai";

const model = new ChatVertexAI({
  model: 'gemini-1.0-pro',
  temperature: 0.01,
  location: 'northamerica-northeast1'
});


Maybe your location value is incorrect, shouldn't it be us-northeast1?
I was able to set the location of ChatVertexAI like this:
from langchain_google_vertexai import ChatVertexAI

llm = ChatVertexAI(
    model="gemini-1.5-flash",
    temperature=0.1,
    location="europe-north1",
)

